# Auto-generating Endpoint in node.js

Tags: node.js, endpoints

I'm trying to make a new endpoint everytime a node is connected to my server,
and will be used only by that endpoint.
But, right now I'm stucked in how to generate a new endpoint while the node.js program is running.

Here is a little ilustration of how I want it to works :
  First, the server (node.js) is up. (Endpoint => /start)
  Second, the node sending it's own uid.
  Third, the server received the data and make a new endpoint based from 
    the node uid it's received.
    (Node uid = aaaa, New endpoint => /aaaa)
  Fourth, everytime a new node is up, it will back to the second step.

I can't any solution or references about this in the internet ...

Any advice ?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you currently setting up endpoints like `/start`? Are you using any libraries/frameworks? If you're using a basic [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server), it'll receives every request made to the server with the [`url` path and query-string](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) simply being a string property. And, it's just as much up to you to define which paths aren't valid as those that are.

Comment: Currently, I'm using the modules from node.js which is called Express. The Express is the modules inside npm packages. To make a new endpoint, simply I just need to write "express.get("/start")", or something like that.... Actually, I'm not quite understand about what you're talking about since I'm a beginner in server things. But, I'll look forward to it and see what I can get... Thank you for your response anyway.. highly appreciated !

Comment: With Express, you can use a parameterized route -- `app.get('/:uid', ...);`. You can retrieve its value with [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) and preprocess it with [`app.param()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) and/or [`router.param()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.param).

Comment: Will this work to multiple nodes which connected to the server in node.js? For example, we have 10 nodes connecting to 1 server. Will the server generates all the endpoints for the 10 nodes ?

Comment: Yes, one route can handle all 10+ nodes. My point before is that the path is just a string to the server -- `console.log(req.url); // "/aaaaa"`. Express handles routing by converting the route you give into a RegExp, then matching that against against the path string. `"/:uid"`, for example, will match any path string with a single segment (separated by slashes) -- `"/foo"`, `"/bar"`, `"/aaaaa"`, etc. while skipping `"/foo/bar"`, etc. You'll have to actually handle it the other way around, checking the `req.params.uid` and refusing any that don't match an active node.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite confident it will works. Let's say that when I post to app.post("/uid1/postdata"), then the app.get("/:uid/data") will become app.get("/uid1/getdata"). But, what if when there are 2 nodes posting to app.post("/uid1/postdata"), and app.post("/uid2/postdata")... When I want to get the uid1 data, because the last post is in uid2 data, instead of uid1 data the server will give me the uid2 data.... bcause in app.get("/:uid/getdata") the :uid will be uid2 not uid1 anymre, it's already "changed". I hope you know what I mean.. Do you have any opinion about this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two NPMs maybe you can try, both packages are automatically detect all the endpoints and list them with **METHODS** (like GET, POST, DELETE etc)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-doc

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints

Hope this will help for someone.